# Meaning of the notation $H \times -$ in category theory

Tags: category-theory, notation

So I saw this notation in Saunders Mac Lane book on category theory.
The original text reads:

If $H$ is a fixed group, show that $G\mapsto H \times G$ defines a functor,

$H \times - : \textbf{GRP}\rightarrow \textbf{GRP}$.

So is there a special meaning behind the notion '$H \times -$' ?

Thanks and cheers !

Comment: It's the map $G\mapsto H\times G$, where of course $\times$ is the categorical product.

Comment: What about the 'minus sign' ?

Comment: It is not a minus sign, it is a placeholder for the unknown group.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks alot